# GestureDetector onFling

Tags: android

I am using `onFling` function to swipe with the `ScrollView`. The problem I am facing is that when I swipe/scroll from top to bottom it swipes my tab from one to another right/left. So I need that my swipe left/right function doesn't work when I scroll.

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        final RelativeLayout detail = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_detail);
        final RelativeLayout photo = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_detail_photo);
        final RelativeLayout pod = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_detail_pod);
        final ToggleButton btn_detail = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_detail);
        final ToggleButton btn_pod = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_pod);
        final ToggleButton btn_photo = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_photo);
        // right to left swipe

        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

            if ((detail.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    && (pod.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    && (photo.getVisibility() == View.GONE)) {
                detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn_photo.setSelected(false);
                btn_pod.setSelected(true);
                btn_detail.setSelected(false);
            } else if ((detail.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    && (pod.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    && (photo.getVisibility() == View.GONE)) {
                detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pod.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_photo.setSelected(true);
                btn_pod.setSelected(false);
                btn_detail.setSelected(false);
            } else if ((detail.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    && (pod.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    && (photo.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)) {
                detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pod.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_photo.setSelected(false);
                btn_pod.setSelected(false);
                btn_detail.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
        // left to right swipe
        else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

            if ((detail.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    && (pod.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    && (photo.getVisibility() == View.GONE)) {
                detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pod.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_photo.setSelected(true);
                btn_pod.setSelected(false);
                btn_detail.setSelected(false);
            } else if ((detail.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    && (pod.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    && (photo.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)) {
                detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn_photo.setSelected(false);
                btn_pod.setSelected(true);
                btn_detail.setSelected(false);
            } else if ((detail.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    && (pod.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    && (photo.getVisibility() == View.GONE)) {
                detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pod.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_photo.setSelected(false);
                btn_pod.setSelected(false);
                btn_detail.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) that allows you to insert your scroll views as pages that you can swipe through by swiping left and right.  That is actually what I did, using the view pager, I created a [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) that returns listviews.  In your case you could return scroll views.   I attached some code to serve as a base for the pager you need to insert to your view pager.

```
public class ViewpagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


private Context mContext;

public ViewpagerListviewsAdapter(Context mContext) {

    this.mContext = mContext;
}
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup group, int position) {


            ListView lView = new ListView(mContext);
                            group.addView(lView);
            return lView;



    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup group, int position, Object object) {

        View view = (View) object;
        group.removeView(view);
        view = null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (number of views in pager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

        return view==object;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear, but if I understand you correctly, you're asking why your code only responds to right/left flings and not to up/down ones. You only have code to handle left/right flings. How could it possibly do anything to respond to an up/down fling? Code along the lines of ...

```
if (e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && 
    Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)
```

... should respond to up/down flings.